# How to display svg image on PDF file with jspdf in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, svg, jspdf, canvg

how to add a logo properly in a pdf file with jspdf in vuejs?

I tried to use this **addSvgAsImage** function like this:

```
const doc = new jsPDF()
const logo = '/src/icons/svg/logo.svg'
doc.addSvgAsImage(logo, 20, 20, 50, 50, null, 'NONE', 0)
```

and I have this error:

```
canvg is not defined
    at Object.et.addSvgAsImage
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally used a png image like that:

```
const logo = require('@/icons/png/logo.png')

const doc = new jsPDF()
var imgLogo = new Image()
imgLogo.src = logo
doc.addImage(imgLogo, 'PNG', xCord, yCord, 24, 8)
```

Comment: we are looking for a solution to add svg image into pdf. Your solution is about .png.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping other people who might have the same problem. It does not make sense to answer your own question by saying you did something completely different instead. At best you can leave a comment on your question, but don't make it an answer. Even worse if you accept your answer. Sorry.